# Invalid attempt to read when no data is present by SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

this is my code

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DayanaP;Integrated Security=True");
        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand test = new SqlCommand("select * from maindata where userid='"+textBox1.Text+ "' and password='" + textBox2.Text + "' ", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = test.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 1)
                MessageBox.Show(dr.GetString(0));
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("123");
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

and that is my database maintable which I used in code

[image]

when I enter name and password I hope to see a message box which show the user first name, but I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' 
occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Concatenating user input into SQL queries and storing passwords in plain text are two bigs **NO-NO**.

Comment: Begin on safer side you can check for dr.HasRows if it return true then only you run your loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already consumed the reader

```
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        count++;
    }
    //dr is now empty
    if (count == 1)
        MessageBox.Show(dr.GetString(0));
```

this is what you need

```
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        count++;
        if (count == 1)
            MessageBox.Show(dr.GetString(0));
    }
```

or shorter

```
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dr.GetString(0));
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("123");
    }
```

or

```
    string rdrZero = "123";
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        rdrZero = GetString(0));
    }
    MessageBox.Show(rdrZero);
```

Answer (score 1):

`dr.Read()` reads the next available row if there is any. If there are no more rows, `dr.Read()` returns `false`.

So in your code:

```
 while (dr.Read())
 {
      count++;
 }
```

you call `dr.Read()` until it returns `false` meaning there is **nothing more to read**.
So your call to `dr.GetString(0)` appears after everything is already read.

One solution could look like this:

```
string s = null;
if (dr.Read()) s = dr.GetString(0);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || dr.Read())
    MessageBox.Show("123");
else
    MessageBox.Show(s);
```

This does the same as (I guess) your code intended to do: shows the returned string if there was exactly one row in the result set.

---

But there are more problems in your code:

1. **Don't insert user input directly into your query!** Your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com). Please use parameterized queries.
2. Instead of `SELECT *` I recommend to explicitly name the columns you want to fetch. How do you know the 0th column will be the string you want?
3. Since you only want the first name, it may be better to use `SELECT firstname...` and use [`ExecuteScalar()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ExecuteReader()`. But probably you want more columns later in your project.

Comment: did you debug what happend? Are there more than one row matching your input? Or is the returned string empty?

Comment: I think there is a missing negation in frontof `dr.Read` in the answer code.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen don't think so, I wanted to mimic the expected behaviour from the original code. That tried to show the result string only if `count == 1` which means that `dr.Read()` should not return `true` a second time. If it does, I show the "123" message box just like OP's code.

Comment: @RenéVogt: Sorry, my fault. But if you need the code for test only, this would be the easiest way (and also not run over all rows if there are more that one: 
`    String test = "123";
    while (dr.Read())  {
        test = dr.GetString(0);
        break;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(test);`

Answer (score 1):

You should check first if the datareader has rows like this example.  You also want to make sure that you are retrieving the value from the datareader inside the while block.

```
 var value = string.empty;
 if(dr.HasRows)
 {    
     while (dr.Read())
     {
        count++;
        value = dr.GetString(0);
     }    
 }
```

Comment: that does not solve the exception which is thrown by the `dr.GetString(0)` call _after_ `dr.Read()` already returned `false`.

Comment: Rene, good point.  I have modified my answer to reflect your comment